# Moved captured std::packaged_task is suddenly const

Tags: c++, asynchronous, concurrency, c++17, packaged-task

As I want to give my async, reactor style pattern, callbacks a result in form of a future from boost::asio, I came across a compile error, i.e. constness clash I don't understand:

When I want to call a packed task in intention to fulfill the underlying promise i.e. make the attached future ready, via a lambda I got constness this compiler errors.

```
#include <future>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::packaged_task<int()> task{
        [] () {
            return 5;
        }
    };
    auto f = [task2 = std::move(task)] () {
        task2();
    };
    f();
}
```

The call of `task2` operator() fails on my gcc compiler with:

> /home/markus/CLionProjects/untitled5/main.cpp:12:15: error: no match
>   for call to ‘(const std::packaged_task) ()’    12 |
>   task2();
>         |               ^ In file included from /home/markus/CLionProjects/untitled5/main.cpp:1:
>   /usr/include/c++/9.3.0/future:1548:7: note: candidate: ‘void
>   std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...)
>   [with _Res = int; _ArgTypes = {}]’   1548 |
>   operator()(_ArgTypes... __args)
>         |       ^~~~~~~~ /usr/include/c++/9.3.0/future:1548:7: note:   passing ‘const std::packaged_task*’ as ‘this’ argument discards
>   qualifiers

If I read this correctly the packaged_task has suddenly become a const one, so the compiler errors that the packed_task::operator() method is not marked as const. The only thing I did between task and task2 is calling the move ctor `packaged_task( packaged_task&& rhs ) noexcept;`, which should AFAIK not change the constness. Obviously I am missing something essential.

Comment: Woops. Thx for marking.

Comment: Funny turns out a coworker had the exact same problem and couldn't understand why also. C++ these days...